# Unexpected behavior when defining variable

Tags: shell-command, defvar

I am trying to get the string value of a variable defined in a Python file and assign it to an elisp variable. The value is held in the variable `org_file` in a file `config.py` in the same directory as my elisp file. In the elisp file I have the following variable declaration (`corgi` is the name of the Python package):

```el
(defvar corgi-org-file-path
    (shell-command-to-string "python -c \"from config import org_file; print org_file\"")
    "Path to org file retrieved from python config file")
```

Now if I evaluate the `shell-command-to-string` call alone, it returns the string path that I want. However, if I evaluate `corgi-org-file-path` after it is defined, I get a Python Traceback in the messages buffer:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named config
```

I am not really sure what is happening here. What am I missing?

Comment: Also [How do I include non-code resources as part of an Emacs package?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17946/454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cwd for that shell command will be based on the `default-directory` for the active buffer at the time your file is loaded; not the directory in which the loaded file resides.

You need to utilise the `load-file-name` variable.

```el
(let ((default-directory (file-name-directory load-file-name)))
  (shell-command-to-string ...))
```

Comment: To make sure I understand what is going on: when I evaluate the `shell-command-to-string` part of the variable definition (using `eval-last-sexp`), the reason that it works as I expect is that I am currently in the same directory as the file (and thus my `cwd` is the right one). On the other hand, when I try to evaluate the variable itself on the next line in the same file, the reason it doesn't work is that the variable was actually defined earlier when the `cwd` was another directory. Is this what is happening?

Comment: I tried confirming this for myself by doing the above experiment, and then reevaluating the entire `defvar` (thinking that if I redefine the variable with the `cwd` as the correct one, it would work), but this had the same unexpected result. Your solution worked, but I am still confused as to why evaluating expression `X` has one result, but when I evaluate a variable that is set to the value returned by expression `X` I get a different result. I think this confusion is why I didn't see this as being a duplicate of my previous question, though the solution is the same

Comment: Re-evaluating the `defvar` for an already-defined variable does not change its value (it would not be possible to `setq` variables for not-yet-loaded libraries in your init file, otherwise, as loading the library would clobber your values). You could `(makunbound 'VAR)` first if you wanted to redefine `VAR`, though; or simply `setq` the new value.

Comment: If it helps to clarify: Create a `~/pwd.el` file containing `(defvar my-cwd (shell-command-to-string "pwd")) (message "cwd: %s" my-cwd)`. Now start a new Emacs, visit some arbitrary file in any directory. Check `C-h v default-directory` and then `M-x load-file RET ~/pwd.el RET` and check the messages with `C-h e`. You'll see that the shell command was executed with cwd equal to the value of `default-directory`. *Whatever* triggers the loading of your library, the value of `default-directory` (which is always buffer-local) for the selected buffer at that time would be the shell command's cwd.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I think I have a better understanding of what is going on now. My problem is that I still haven't taken the time to sit down and really *learn* elisp, and just try to hack my way through whatever problems I need to solve without fully understanding what I am doing or what the consequences are, or why something works or doesn't work. However, through asking and answering questions on this site I am slowly getting there in spite of myself!